# How to maximize strength/torque of a joint?

Tags: motors, torque, robotics

I'm an elec engineering student and so mechanics isn't my best field, apologies if the question is straightforward.

If i have a robotic joint (e.g elbow or knee). What are the best methods for maximizing the strength at that joint?

*(Assume an infinite power supply to any devices used and indestructible materials used in all components so nothing would break under great loads).*

For a servo motor at said joint that is coupled with a gearbox to increase torque and lifting amount, what other mechanical devices could be added in conjunction with that to further boost the strength/torque of the joint. (Assume any devices work perfectly in sync with the servo and other devices added from a control system point of view).

Comment: Please post a sketch so people can understand your idea and need for improvement.

Comment: If you state indestructible materials then there can be no problem with the joints… Or is your assumption incorrect?

Comment: i wonder if it's one of those optimization questions like given infinite strength materials but finite strength of motor and finite modulus of elasticity (and coefficient of friction), what geometry would minimize the overall energy losses due to friction from a certain motion and loading.  maybe i'm still thinking of jewel bearings...

Answer (score 1):

i) using a strong material which shows high strength at plastic failure or fracture (like choosing a steel variant instead of general aluminum).

ii) replacing that single joint with two joints at that location, a bit apart from each other.

iii) making the joint holes of bigger diameter.

iv) avoiding passage of all the possible forces (shear and axial) and all the possible moments (bending and torque) through that joint, by modifying the geometric structure which that joint is a part of.

Comment: Re iv: so add a second or third joint - any mass implications?

Comment: Dividing the force transfer into two separate joints. Since making one big joint might not be possible due to geometric limits.

Comment: I think that's correct. Look at the mechanics of the [patella](https://journals.lww.com/em-news/PublishingImages/Procedural%20Pause/patella%20drawing.png), for example. In a way, having the extra pivot point is similar to the "extra" [linkage](https://www.scissorliftfactory.com/Content/uploads/2020583952/202001021636399994830.jpg) found in a machine like an excavator... (not directly analogous though, just the concept of adding more pivots than the minimum)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, intuitively nature is our best model. our shoulder is a good example of a joint, strength, range of motion, and scalable control.

You can thread a needle with the same arm that can lift 100kilograms or can knock out the adversary in a boxing match.

In a robot, any joint has to be designed as an integral part of the system first. An arm tasked with lifting a 10kg load may undergo 50kg torque or acceleration transferred from another arm or another articulation.

Basically, the Hinges and bearings are supported by larger, thicker housing with a geometry designed to minimize the stresses by getting wider at high moment/torque areas, while not getting in the way of the range of motion of the arm.
In the diagram, we see the joints are tapered out to be stronger while maintaining overall flexibility of the arm.

'

[image: robot arm]

Comment: Hmm.. The big joints in our bodies are amazing things. The ability to take load comes from multiple layers of muscle and connective tissue, the shoulder blades as a linkage. I think the bones are quite small for the loads involved, compared to the proportions of machines we would build from material of the equivalent strength.

Comment: My right thumb is re-implanted, cut by a skill saw. I had to relearn to control it. it's pure magic!! the thumb set us apart from other mammals. the body as a machine is unbelievably beautiful.

Comment: Yikes, Glad they can repair that now! I broke my thumb once after a foolish adventure on a mechanical bull. Definitely gave me an appreciation for some of this.

Answer (score 1):

From what you are describing, its best to be clear that in a robotic arm there are two separate things to consider:

1. the robotic arm must be sufficiently **sturdy** to perform the work without failing (breaking down). I'll call that **"Mechanical Strength"**
2. The robotic arm must have sufficient **power** to raise the load that is carrying. I'll call that "Power".

Those two are separate, however both of them can be thought of as **strength**, so its good to be explicit about it.

Regarding no.1 increasing the crosssections or use different materials with higher stiffness and strength (more examples).

Regarding no.2 you'd usually need to add a larger motor.

IMHO the difficult thing is to find the right combination of the two, because usually, when the power goes up, the mechanical strength needs to increase.

Of course when you could have a situation where you have a high "mechanical strength" without suffiecient power. However that is also inefficient.

### maximisation and controller

In order to achieve maximisation of the robotic arm capabilities, an intelligent controller is required. Most robotic arms have controllers that take into account what load the robot currently is carrying, and calculate based on mass moments of inertia the expected torque required (and expected) at different point of the trajectory that they calculate.

So they can use that information to maximize the capabilities of the robotic  arm (minimizing power requirements and also structural stresses). Or select a different strategy (e.g. shortest distance etc).

So for a given robotic arm, the extend of maximisation is determined by the controller.